# Yii2-user Dektrium - Registration Controller not exists error when i override

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user

I encountered a strange issue today with Yii2.

I am using yii2-user extension and i have overridden the RegistrationController in my app folder to add few more features.

The thing is its working fine in my XAMPP but not in the server (Cent OS).

Im getting the below error.

```
**ReflectionException

Class app\controllers\user\RegistrationController does not exist**
```

My config is...

```
    'modules' => [
    'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'layout'=>'@app/views/layouts/main.php',
            'mailer' => [
                'viewPath' => '@app/views/mail',
            ],
            'modelMap' => [
                'User' => 'app\models\User',
                'RegistrationForm' => 'app\models\RegistrationForm',
                'Profile' => 'app\models\Profile',
            ],
            'controllerMap' => [
                'registration' => 'app\controllers\user\RegistrationController',
                'security' => [ 'class' => 'dektrium\user\controllers\SecurityController', 'layout' => '@app/views/layouts/login', ],
            ],
    ],
],
```

My new controller file is...

```
namespace app\controllers\user;
use Yii;
use app\models\RegistrationForm;
use dektrium\user\controllers\RegistrationController as BaseRegistrationController;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

class RegistrationController extends BaseRegistrationController
{
.......
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using advanced template ?

Comment: No.. basic template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app\controller..... filname  don't exist   or don't match cause lower/uppercase difference between OS 
 the problem is related to the fact unix is case sensitive and windows not .. check for you class/filename    if you have a lowercase (typically  ath the begin  of camel case)

Comment: what is the name of your directory  project ?   and have replied the same structure in you controller ?

Comment: **csot** is the directory name of the project... I tried it but not working

Comment: have you replied the same directory structure  for RegistrationController?

Comment: Actually, the config i have now is working fine in my local environment but it throws error only in the server which is running on Cent OS.. So, i assumed it might be related to any case sensitive issue.

Comment: Yes I replaced the "app" with "csot" in my controller namespace as well..

Comment: Its windows - XAMPP

Comment: Then the problem is related to the fact unix is case sensitive and windows not .. check for you class/filename    if you have a lowercase (typically  ath the begin  of camel case)  .. i have update the answer  .. with this indication .. usea app instead od project name if this work locally ..

Comment: Yes! You are correct.. I used the filename as Registrationcontroller instead of RegistrationController. Thanks for your help!